# MPI_Gather Error Buffer overflow - changing size of buffer

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I've stuck at one point during testing my parallel program. Whenever I create 'pS' arrays, my program crashes on MPI_Gather() function with error "MPIDI_CH3_Receive_data_found(129) ... 4998 bytes recived but buffer size 4996". The values are exemplary however first number is always higher than second. I suppose that MPI_Bcast causes this error, but I have no idea how to resolve it. Additionally, program works purely correctly when the 'pS' arrays have the same size on each process.
EDIT.
After removing MPI_Bcast the problem still exist.
EDIT.
When I defined constant recvcount greater than the greatest sendcnt size it works properly but idk why my primary conception doesn't work.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);

    //Start the timer
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int myRank = 0;
    int numProcs = 1;
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myRank);
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcs);

    int size_s = atoi(argv[1]);
    bool *S;
    if(myRank == 0){
        S = new bool[size_s+1];
    }

    unsigned long lowValue = BlockLow (myRank, numProcs, maxNumber);

    unsigned long highValue = BlockHigh (myRank, numProcs, maxNumber);

    ...

    unsigned long size = (highValue - lowValue)/2 + 1;

    ...

    bool *pS = new bool[size];

    ...

    while(...){
        ...
        MPI_Bcast(&var, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    //here I've been getting pS array with diffrent size because I create in processes 'pS' arrays with diffrent sizes
    MPI_Gather(pS, size, MPI_C_BOOL, S, size, MPI_C_BOOL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

unsigned long BlockLow(unsigned int procId, unsigned int numProcs, unsigned long maxNumber){
    unsigned long low = ((maxNumber-1) / numProcs)*procId + 3;
    if((low & 1) == 0) low--;
    return low;
}


unsigned long BlockHigh(unsigned int procId, unsigned int numProcs, unsigned long maxNumber){
    return((BlockLow(procId+1,numProcs,maxNumber)) - 2);
}
```

Comment: How do you BlockLow and BlockHigh functions work? It's unclear how your arrays sizes relate to each other, which means we can't verify the math.

Comment: ok I've just been added definitions of functions. I'm sorry for my oversight.